# Why am I able to push to a cloned private repo with just my username and email?

Tags: git

In a machine which has not stored it's public ssh key in my github account, I have specified my github username and email in the `~/.gitconfig` file.

By running

```
git clone https://username@github.com/username/private_repo_name.git
```

I was able to clone the private repo without any prompt for password.

To my horror, I was able to perform commits and pushes to remote from this repo. Why is this so, is this not a security risk?

Comment: Check your `credential.helper` config. I bet your credentials have been saved already. (btw. you are using `https` and not `ssh`)

Comment: I've checked both my `~/.gitcofig` and `repo_dir/.git/config`, and there isnt any `credential` inside either

Answer (score 0):

HTTP uses your `~/.netrc` for authentication.

Comment: This machine is a windows machine, I could not find any `~/.netrc` file